# Some utf8 chars allowed in python source, some not

Tags: unicode, python-3.x

I've noticed that I can not use all unicode characters in my python source code.

While

```
def 价(何):
```

is perfectly allright (albeit nonsensical [probably?]),

```
def N(N₀, t, λ) -> 'N(t)':
```

this isn't allowed (the subscript zero that is).

I also can't use some other characters, most of which I recognise as something other than letters (mathematical operators for example). I always thought that if I just stick to the rules I know, i.e. composing names from letters and numbers, with a letter as the first character, all will be okay. Now, the subscript zero is clearly a 'number'. so my impression was wrong.

I know I should avoid using *special* characters. However, the function definition above (the exponential decay one that is) seems to me perfectly reasonable - because it will never change, and it so elegantly conveys all the information needed for another programmer to use it.

My question therefore, exactly which characters are allowed and which aren't? And where?

**Edit**
All right I seem not to have been clear enough. I am using python3, so there is no need for declaring the encoding of the source file. Apparent I thought from then fact that my Chinese function definition works.

My question concerns why some characters are allowed there, while others aren't.
**The subscript zero raises an error**, invalid character in identifier, **but the blackboard bold zero works.** Both equally *special* I'd say.

I'd like to know if there are any general rules that apply not just to my situation, there must be. It seems that my error is not an accident.

Edit 2:

The **answer** courtesy of Beau Martínez, pointing me to the language reference, where i should have looked in the first place:

http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/home/loewis/table-3131.html
It appears the characters that are allowed are all chosen.

Comment: FWIW, I also find it odd that a language with a stronghold in scientific conputing allows in identifiers “ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE”, “ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT FIVE”, “EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT FIVE”, “DEVANAGARI DIGIT FIVE”, “BENGALI DIGIT FIVE”, “GURMUKHI DIGIT FIVE”, <20 other 5's>, “FULLWIDTH DIGIT FIVE” — but not a subscript “5”.  Especially “fullwidth” is not a language on its own but a letter variant, as is a subscript.  Besides, “ℌ” or “ℂ” are also mere variants, yet they are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), Python 3 allows a large variety of characters as identifiers.

That zero subscript character seems like a number, but it isn't for Python; Python only treats 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 as numbers. It is in fact a character, so you can use it as an identifier (it's as if it were, instead, for example, a greek character such as Phi).

Importantly, how easily can you type those characters with your keyboard? I don't want to pull up the character map every time I have to call your functions, for example. Calling it "maximum_decay_rate" or something much more intuitive to any user, not just a Physics major, makes your code more readable.

If you say it isn't allowed, it's probably because you haven't specified the [character encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) for your source file. It can be specified by having `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (or which ever the encoding) at the beginning of your source file.

Comment: As you can see, I was only using 'special' characters where they would never have to be typed by anybody, unless the universe changes it's mind about exponential decay. :-) But yes, it should probably be called decay(). I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 3):

Tell Python what the proper encoding is:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Either...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

or

```
# coding=utf-8
```

As far as what characters are actually allowed in variable names, typically the restriction is alphabetic characters, digits, and underscores.

The "subscript zero" is not actually a digit, it's a subscript.

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Each Unicode character has specific 'properties', to be found in the Unicode Character Database, and for our purpose the properties from so called General Category are most important. They allow to partition all the characters into large groups:

- letters (`L`)
- numbers (`N`)
- marks (`M`)
- punctuations (`P`)
- symbols (`S`)
- separators (`Z`)
- other (`C`)

The groups have subgroups, for example `Lu` is `Uppercase_Letter`. According to the Python Language Reference (3.4.1), one should first normalize the sequence of characters into NFKC form (which in practice means decomposing characters with diacritics and 'simplifying' them, for example changing subscript `0` into normal `0`). Then, the start of the identifier should be either an underscore or a letter (the whole Letter group plus `Nl` - letterlike numbers), plus a few other  letterlike symbols. It gets much more interesting when we look at characters that are allowed as continuation of the identifier. Additionally, we can use: `Decimal_Numbers` (`Nd`), which are in fact digits from 0 to 9, but in many guises, for example `MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE DIGIT NINE`, which is character `\U0001D7FF` (all together 70 characters); most marks (`M`), with the exception of enclosing marks (`Me`) - here we have all the diacritics (accents); all characters from subgroup `Pc` - punctuation connectors, so not only underscore, but also various ties (10 characters); some additional digit-like characters (for example Ethiopic digits 0 to 9); middle dots (2 characters).

As seen from the above, `N` with a subscript `0` should be accepted as an identifier. When I tried to paste it from Word, both IDLE and Wing 101 inserted the normalized forms into the editor (i.e. `N0`). I suspect the author of the question tried to use a subscript character that could not be properly normalized.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  There is exactly one subscript zero in Unicode, and it is not allowed in a Python identifier.